# Instagram Log out from a cordova built android app using instagram api for authorization

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, instagram

Im building a cordova android app built using jquery,jquery-mobile,html5 etc.
The authorization to my android app is using instagrams oAuth api. I have provided a log out option in my android app, onclicking the logout option the user should get logged out from instagram only from my map, and then get redirect to the "index.html" page of my app. I have tried out to redirect user to log out using `

```
location.href = "https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/"
```

but this link redirect the user to the log out of instagram page and shows instagram webpage .
How I can I achieve the following:

```
1. Log out from instagram account-only from my app, not instagram app.
2. Redirect the user to the index.html page of my app.
```

Also I have tried all the previously mentioned ideas of the above topic on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im making android app using html5, I did the following: Redirect the user to a html5 page containing following code:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">                 
  <iframe style="display: none;" 
    src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0">
  </iframe>                          
  <div id = "loading" style="text-align: center; display:block; margin-top: 150px;">
    <img alt="" src="/css/themes/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="46px" height="46px">
    <br>
    <font style="text-align: center;">Logging Out...</font>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the user to a html page which will have the following code:

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content"> 
        <iframe style="display: none;" src="https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0"></iframe>

        <div id = "loading" style="text-align: center; display:block; margin-top: 150px;">
                <img alt="" src="/css/themes/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="46px" height="46px">
                <br><font style="text-align: center;">Logging Out...</font>
        </div>

    </div>
```

then setTimeout() as below:

```
setTimeout(callIndex,2000);
```

where callIndex() will redirect to index.html using location.href;